# Logstash - How to filter by [tags]

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

Logstash filter by tags for different websites

Issue: I have multiple websites inside a single IIS Server.. I want to add a "Tag" for each of the log files i am sending towards logstash

This is my logstash forwarder config

Each log file represents a different website.. so i want to add tags for each of these logs and be able to filter by this particular tag.

"logs\svr05\ex*",

```
{
  "network": {
    "servers": [ "logsvr1.logs.local:5000", "logsvr2.logs.local:5000" ],
    "timeout": 15,
    "ssl ca": "logstash-forwarder-new.crt"
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [
         "logs\\svr08\\ex*",
         "logs\\svr05\\ex*",
         "logs\\svr04\\ex*",
         "logs\\svr03\\ex*"
       ],
      "fields": { "type": "iis" },
      "dead time": "24h" 
        }
   ]
}
```

This is my IIS config for logstash..

```
filter {
    if [type] == "iis" {
            if [message] =~ "^#" {
                            drop {}
            }
            grok {
                    break_on_match => false
                    match => [
                            "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp} %{IPORHOST:s-sitename} %{IPORHOST:s-ip} %{URIPROTO:cs-method} %{URIPATH:cs-uri-stem} (?:%{NOTSPACE:cs_query}|-) %{NUMBER:src_port} %{NOTSPACE:cs_username} %{IP:clientip} %{NOTSPACE:useragent} %{NUMBER:sc-substatus} %{NUMBER:sc_win32_status} %{NUMBER:sc-bytes} %{NUMBER:cs-bytes} %{NUMBER:timetaken}"
                    ]
            }

            date {

                    locale => "en"
                    match => [ "log_timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
                    target => "@timestamp"
                    timezone => "Indian/Maldives"
            }
            useragent {
                    source=> "useragent"
                    prefix=> "browser"
            }
            geoip {
                    source => "clientip"
                    target => "geoip"
                    add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
                    add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
            }

            mutate {
                    add_field => [ "src_ip", "%{clientip}" ]
                    convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
                    replace => [ "@source_host", "%{clientip}" ]
                    replace => [ "@message", "%{message}" ]
                    rename => [ "cs_method", "method" ]
                    rename => [ "cs_stem", "request" ]
                    rename => [ "useragent", "agent" ]
                    rename => [ "cs_username", "username" ]
                    rename => [ "sc_status", "response" ]
                    rename => [ "timetaken", "time_request" ]
           }
    }
}
filter
  {
    if [type] == "iis" {
            mutate {
                    remove_field => [ "clientip", "host", "hostname", "logtime" ]
            }
    }
}
```

Suppose I want to send logs different apps

app1.egov.mv
app2.egov.mv

how can i add tags for these different IIS applications? and filter them in the discovery module to make graphs for specific websites using the tag? :|

regards,

Ismail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know how to add the `type` field so just use the same method to add another field containing the name of the host:

```
{
  ...,
  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [
         "logs\\svr08\\ex*",
         "logs\\svr05\\ex*",
         "logs\\svr04\\ex*",
         "logs\\svr03\\ex*"
      ],
      "fields": {
        "type": "iis",
        "virtualhost": "app1.egov.mv"
      },
      "dead time": "24h" 
    }
  ]
}
```

Obviously, if your different logfile patterns are for different servers you'll have to split your configuration:

```
{
  ...,
  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [
         "logs\\svr08\\ex*"
      ],
      "fields": {
        "type": "iis",
        "virtualhost": "app1.egov.mv"
      },
      "dead time": "24h" 
    },
    {
      "paths": [
         "logs\\svr05\\ex*"
      ],
      "fields": {
        "type": "iis",
        "virtualhost": "app2.egov.mv"
      },
      "dead time": "24h" 
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Another option (that I prefer) is to have the web server itself include the hostname in each log entry.